# Python: best practice to manage logging handlers

Tags: python, logging

What's the best practice for logger instantiation? Currently, I'm using this to create a logger:

```
def create_logger(logger_name='default_logger_name', tags={"application": "default-app", "environment": "development"}):
    handler = logging_loki.LokiQueueHandler(
        Queue(-1),
        url="https://somewhere",
        tags=tags,
        auth=("some", "thing="),
        version="1",
    )

    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.addHandler(get_console_handler())
    return logger

def get_console_handler():
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

    return console_handler
```

and then calling

```
self.logger = create_logger(__name__)
```

in any class where I want logging.
This has two problems. The first one is that my class is suddenly coupled to loki which is obviously bad. The second problem is that even if I wasn't using any handler that was using extra modules, I noticed that during unit testing, I have to remove the handlers explicitly between different tests as I otherwise would get 2x the output for the test that was ran second, 3x the output for the third and so on as duplicate handlers keep getting added without ever being removed.
What kind of pattern should I use to avoid these issues? The first thing that occurred to me is to pass the logger creation method in the class constructor. This solves the first problem but does not solve the issue of having to remove the handlers. The second would be to pass a logger instance and handle everything outside of the class (like handler removal between tests). However, this would still leave me with having to do an explicit handler removal which feels a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended practice is to add handlers to the root logger only, and do it only once using a configuration API such as [`logging.config.dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig), calling that from your `main()` function or a `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. You might need a factory function to instantiate a custom handler, such as

```
def loki_handler_factory(url, tags, auth, version):
    return logging_loki.LokiQueueHandler(
        Queue(-1),
        url=url,
        tags=tags,
        auth=auth,
        version=version,
    )
```

which you can then use via configuration like so:

```
handlers:
  loki:
    '()' : mypkg.util.loki_handler_factory
    level   : INFO
    url: https://somewhere
    tags:
        application: 'default-app'
        environment: development
    auth: [some, 'thing=']
    version: '1'
```

And configuring could be

```
import logging.config
import yaml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('logging_conf.yaml') as f:
        d = yaml.safe_load(f)
    logging.config.dictConfig(d)
```

The above is just a partial YAML snippet for the configuration; you can refer to the linked documentation for more information. You can of course use JSON or Python code for the configuration dictionary, too.

Comment: I had to change some minor things such as defining a root logger in the config file and auth expecting a tuple instead of a list but your solution worked great otherwise. Thanks.